# Ask user to continue viewing the next 5 lines of data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the next 5 data rows without writing a loop every time ([:5], [5:10], [10:15],etc...). I have some idea but I been stuck on this one for awhile, what are some ways to go about this to get the user to show the next 5?

```
def raw_data(df):
ask_user = input('Would you like to view more raw data for the city selected? \nPrint yes or no: ')
while True:
    if ask_user == 'yes':
        return df.iloc[:5]
    else:
        break
```

Comment: please format/indent your code properly since Python is whitespace-sensitive. For the 5 counter, use variable to track the range and add to it

Answer (score 3):

Add a variable that accumulates each time the function runs. (Let's call it `runs`) Initialize it outside of the function and add one to it inside of the function. From here, multiply it by 5 to get your range.

```
runs = 0
def raw_data(df):
    while True: 
        ask_user = input('Would you like to view more raw data for the city selected? \nPrint yes or no: ') 
        if ask_user == 'yes': 
            runs += 1 #Adds 1 to current value, same as runs = runs + 1
            return df.iloc[(x-1)*5:x*5]
        elif ask_user == 'no':
            return
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a control in case len(df) is not divisible by 5

Comment: I do not understand the behaviour of this loop - what controls it? if user said no you just go to infinity?

Comment: That didn't work for me. I would still like it to ask the user if they would like to continue with the next 5 lines.

Comment: @WalterSolares Sorry, I based it off of your code and forgot to move the input into the loop. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak There is a `break` statement to exit the loop if the user says no.

Comment: I think in your particular implementation the user has no chance to say no.

Comment: Whoops, misunderstood the original intended logic using the while loop to ask for input instead of asking after each update. Fixed and edited code.

Comment: Outside the loop )

Comment: input() is not a great practice inself, but I think now you managed the intended behaviour